# "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

Tags: c#, ado.net

I got this error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0.

My code is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;

namespace LibrarySystem
{
    public partial class PIDD : Form
    {
        public PIDD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            frmMed Med = new frmMed();
            Med.Show();

            var conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
            //var command = new SqlCommand("Patient.dbo.P_ID", connection);
            var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT P_ID FROM Patient WHERE id='" + textBox1.Text + "",connection);

            connection.Open();
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                // No entry found
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public SqlConnection connection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write ID that already exists in the DB and check if ID Correct ,, then show it in next fram ,,

Comment: Nothing makes sense here. What is the problem? What error information do you have (And where in the code does that happen?) What is frmMed, and why do you close the PIDD form on click? Where are you trying to write anything?

Comment: `SqlConnection("ConnectionString");`? Is it your actual code or just random fake sample? If looking for debugging help you need to provide - code, exact error message with location where it happened, expected and observed behavior. Note that Sub-par formatting of code likely will earn you some downvotes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.* is just an ArgumentException message from giving a bad connection string to the [`SqlConnection(string)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0(v=vs.110).aspx): give it a [valid SQL Server connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) (i.e. not `"ConnectionString"`), and you will be ready to move on to tackling the other issues in your code.

For reference, you can see how I quickly, minimally morphed your code to confirm the source of given error message in LINQPad 4:

[image]